# Logical error comparing two ranges cells values

Tags: vba, find, cell

This program aims to compare two named ranges in two sheets. If the cells values are found in both sheets it highlights cells in green otherwise in red.
In my code below, I get a logical error.

I compare the results in the two sheets manually but I get totally different results.

```
Public Sub FindBtn_Click()

range1Name = namedRange1TxtBox
range2Name = namedRange2TxtBox
sheet1Name = Sheet1txt
sheet2Name = Sheet2txt

Dim range1No(), range2No() As Variant
range1No() = Range(range1Name)
range2No() = Range(range2Name)

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim cell As Variant 'Range
For i = LBound(range1No()) To UBound(range1No())
For j = LBound(range2No()) To UBound(range2No())
     Set cell = Worksheets(sheet1Name).Range(range1Name).Find(what:=Worksheets(sheet2Name).Range(range2Name).Cells(i, 1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not cell Is Nothing Then ' if jde cell value is found in tops then green jde cell
Worksheets(sheet1Name).Range(range1Name).Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Else
Worksheets(sheet1Name).Range(range1Name).Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of " & UBound(range1No()) '& Format(i / 9331, "%")
Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Without spending a while on in, I'm not too sure what's actually wrong with your code. But how about doing it this way (I substituted strings in the variables so I could make it work locally).

```
Public Sub FindBtn_Click()

    range1Name = "firstrange"
    range2Name = "secondrange"
    sheet1Name = "Sheet1"
    sheet2Name = "Sheet2"

    Dim range1cell As Range
    Dim range2cell As Range

    For Each range1cell In Range(range1Name)
        range1cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        For Each range2cell In Range(range2Name)
            If range1cell.Value = range2cell.Value Then
                range1cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                Exit For
            End If
        Next range2cell
    Next range1cell

End Sub
```

On looking closer, I notice that while you're looping through values of j you don't seem to refer to j anywhere else.

Comment: your code didn't work either :(

Thank you anyways
I have figured a way for doing this with the find function find my post :)

Answer (score 0):

the following code solved my problem basicly I don't know how to use the find function properly. below a code that does the job :)

Thanks :)

```
Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range
Dim add1 As Variant

With Worksheets("JDE").Range("JS_No")
For Each cell2 In Worksheets("TOPS").Range("TechID")
Set cell1 = .Find(cell2, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not cell1 Is Nothing Then
    add1 = cell1.Address
    Do
    cell1.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    cell2.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing: " & add1
    Loop While Not cell1 Is Nothing And cell1.Address <> add1
End If
Next cell2



End With
```